# How to display 2d image on the screen unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, graphics, texture2d

I created a unity application for desktop and mobile platforms. There is a map on top-left corner of the screen. I draw circle on this map each frame. The position of the circle changes at runtime anytime.

To do for this task, I draw circle on texture and draw this texture. This code works on emulator but not android phone or tablet. I don't see any circle on the map.

My code is here :

```
TextAsset imageAsset; // .png changes to .png.bytes. And the file dragged to this variable on inspector.

Start () {
  texture.LoadImage(imageAsset.bytes); 
}

void OnGUI () {

  Circle(texture, x, y, Color.red);

  if (Event.current.type.Equals(EventType.Repaint))
  {
    Graphics.DrawTexture(new Rect(..), texture);
  }
}
```

Some people say deprecated `OnGUI`. But if I create a button in `OnGUI`, it is displayed at runtime on android.

I tried another solution. I create a 3d plane object on my scene, and drag .png file as texture. But I don't change this texture using `Texture2D` variable that is drawed circle.

Comment: why dont you use `sprites`?

Comment: divide the x and y positions by screen width and height in your Rect

Answer (score 0):

You should use sprites, and why did you use the OnGui Function instead of the Update ?

Maybe get a look on the asset store : 2DToolkit

Comment: `if (Event.current.type.Equals(EventType.Repaint))`returns only OnGUI function, not Update. I will try to use sprite.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resolution of your device and your image?

I'm asking this because you should consider change of resolutions between your computer's screen and yours device.

As you can see [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawTexture.html) your rect values must be in pixels.

I recommend you to use [raw image](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html) for loading your texture, a [Canvas](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html) for handling drawing and [RectTransform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html) for controlling your circle position instead.

These components have many functionalities to deal with this resolutions problems that may happen.